# C# EntityFramework 6.0 Querying Decimal > 0 Gives No Result

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

So I have set the model here:

```
public class Stock
{
    [Key]
    //[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid StockId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    .....
    public decimal Remaining { get; set; }
}
```

Also with fluent mapping:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(mb);
        mb.HasDefaultSchema("dbo");

        mb.Entity<Stock>().Property(m => m.Remaining).HasPrecision(16, 3);
        ....
    }
```

So the precision is 3 decimal points.

It is so weird when I querying with linq:

```
IQueryable<StockDetail> stocks = (from s in db.Stocks .... where s.Remaining > 0);
stocks.Any() --> is false;
```

The `where s.Remaining > 0` is the problem, how to fix this?

---

### EDIT

The actual query:

```
IQueryable<StockDetail> stocks = (from s in db.Stocks
    join items in db.Items on s.Item equals items.ItemId
    join types in db.ItemTypes on s.ItemType equals types.ItemTypeId
    join colors in db.ItemColors on s.ItemColor equals colors.ItemColorId
    join units in db.ItemUnits on s.Unit equals units.ItemUnitId
    join buyers in db.Buyers on new { Buyer = s.Buyer } equals new { Buyer = (Guid?)buyers.BuyerId } into temp2
    from buyers in temp2.DefaultIfEmpty(null)
    join suppliers in db.Suppliers.DefaultIfEmpty() on new { Supplier = s.Supplier } equals new { Supplier = (Guid?)suppliers.SupplierId } into temp3
    from suppliers in temp3.DefaultIfEmpty(null)
    join op in db.UserProfiles on s.Operator equals op.UserId
    join curr in db.Currencies on s.Currency equals curr.CurrencyId
    let sales = db.Sales.Where(m => m.SId == s.Sales).FirstOrDefault()
    join parent in db.Stocks on s.Parent equals parent.StockId
    where s.Remaining > 0 
    select new StockDetail()
    {
        Buyer = buyers != null ? (Guid?)buyers.BuyerId : null,
        BuyerName = buyers != null ? buyers.Name : null,
        Supplier = suppliers.SupplierId,
        SupplierName = suppliers.Name,
        Code = s.Code,
        Color = colors.ItemColorId,
        ColorCode = colors.Code,
        ColorName = colors.Color,
        DateCreated = s.DateCreated,
        Gramation = s.Gramation,
        Item = items.ItemId,
        ItemName = items.Name,
        LastEdited = s.LastEdited,
        Operator = op.UserId,
        OperatorName = op.UserName,
        PO = s.PO,
        Remaining = s.Remaining,
        SC = s.SC,
        Qty = s.Qty,
        Setting = s.ItemSetting,
        StockId = s.StockId,
        Type = types.ItemTypeId,
        TypeName = types.Type,
        Unit = units.ItemUnitId,
        UnitName = units.Unit,
        Lot = s.Lot,
        AvgPrice = s.AvgPrice,
        Currency = curr.CurrencyName,
        CurrencyId = s.Currency,
        Note = s.Note,
        Purchase = s.Purchase,
        Sales = s.Sales,
        POIn = s.POIn,
        FromFactory = s.FromFactory,
        OutDeliveryNo = sales != null ? sales.InvoiceNo : "",
        Spec = s.Spec,
        DesignCode = s.DesignCode
    });
```

Comment: Comparisons aren't broken. Post the *actual* query and a sample of the data. There may not be any values greater than 0. Or the rest of the query filters out those results. Perhaps you're connecting to the *wrong* database.

Comment: If I remove the where clause, it retrieves all the data. So the problem lies in `s.Remaining > 0`. Tried with `s.Remaining > (decimal)0` still does not work. The query is super long.

Comment: `The query is super long.` that's the problem. Why would an *ORM* query be long? It's meant to load entities, not perform joins or complex reporting queries. What does it do? And how can anyone help without the query itself?

Comment: You are right. I just posted the query.

Comment: OK, I suggest you fix your context. ORMs don't need joins, the M stands for Mapping. The relations should be expressed as navigation properties on the objects. It's the *ORM's* job to generate the JOINs

Comment: I don't think I can do this without creating a new database (from scratch). It is already polluted with a large number of data.

Comment: With the proper relation, all you'd need to do to get the stocks and related items would be `db.Stocks.Where(s=>s.Remaining>2).Select(s=>...)`. You can access the related entities in the `Select` lambda directly. Eg `Select(s=> new {s.Buyer.BuyerId,....})`

Comment: The database has nothing to do with the DbContext. They are *completely different* models and actually, products and machines. Even if you create the database from a specific context, you can use as many contexts as needed

Comment: Besides, the *tables* won't change if you add relations, only the generated mappings.

Comment: What does `db.Stocks.Any(s => s.Remaining > 0)` return?

Comment: Can you please reduce your query to the [MCVE standard](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? There is a lot of unrelated information that distracts from the actual problem. You're also very likely to stumble on more information (or even the solution) when you reduce the problem to its core elements.